# Fix function on how to find & replace a string within a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have made a function here:

```
function locationOfVideo(){//Outputs video location div according to post text
    var ytVideoDiv = '<div class="youtube-video"><div id="<?php echo $divName; ?>-video"></div></div>';

    $j('#main .content:contains("<--video-->")').replace('<--video-->', ytVideoDiv);
}
```

I thought this would work, but I am sorely mistaken and a bit tired. Anyways, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `$j('#main .content:contains("<--video-->")')` returns a jQuery object, not a string. If you want to modify the elements content, you have to access its content first.

Comment: @FelixKling It even does not return the `.content`, http://jsfiddle.net/NmKe4/4/

Comment: @xdazz: Interesting. Maybe the `<>` somehow break it. If you only search for `video` it seems to work fine... strange.

Comment: @FelixKling in the answer i chose, they mention that <--video--> is probably a bad placeholder so I used {video} instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<--video-->` in your html, change to some other like `{video}`.

Then do it with:

```
$('#main .content:contains("{video}")').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace('{video}', ytVideoDiv);
});
```

Comment: I dont know what I am doing wrong but i created the scenario in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hP939/1/

Comment: strange because it doesn't work on wordpress. I will just play around with it and hopefully see why not.

Comment: i keep getting this in the console: window.toolset = new CreativeToolset(); And i have no idea what that means

Answer (score 3):

replace is a plain js function to replace part of a string or similar, not to replace the content of a jQuery object.

If the goal is to replace all the content in the selected element, and if you're using the right selector, you could use `html()` and do :

```
$j('#main .content:contains("<--video-->")').html(ytVideoDiv);
```

or to replace just the string `<--video-->` :

```
$j('#main .content:contains("<--video-->")').html(function(i,html) {
    return html.replace('&lt;--video--&gt;', ytVideoDiv)
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LuWRs/3/)

Comment: I would just like to replace <--video--> text, if easily possible

Comment: The 2nd param passed to the html callback is the old HTML, so you don't need to read innerHTML, but otherwise I agree entirely.

Comment: @adeneo `$j('#main .content:contains("<--video-->")')` doesn't return what you think, check it http://jsfiddle.net/NmKe4/2/

Comment: @xdazz - Do you think has something to do with the fact that you added a `!` to make it a comment ?

Comment: @xdazz - or the actual selector in the question http://jsfiddle.net/NmKe4/6/ - have no idea why your example is'nt working though ?? strange as it works perfectly fine with an ID, but I do agree that `gt` and `lt` used this way should probably be avoided!

Comment: @adeneo That's strange, maybe `<--video-->` break the html tags causing the strange behavior...

Comment: @xdazz - yes, it's probably misinterpreting it somehow, but just using `:contains("--video--")` will select 'almost' the same element, and chances are it will get it right : http://jsfiddle.net/NmKe4/8/

Comment: @adeneo for whatever reason the code doesn't work. I think i made my exact scenario and i made it easier for jquery to find the right element. http://jsfiddle.net/NmKe4/9/

Comment: @NilsR - nope, jsfiddle does'nt work that way, but if you move it around a little bit it works fine, see : http://jsfiddle.net/NmKe4/11/

Comment: @adeneo hmm then for whatever reason it isn't working on wordpress. I guess i have to play around with it and find out.

Comment: @adeneo i keep getting this in the console: window.toolset = new CreativeToolset(); 
And i have no idea what that means

Comment: @NilsR - does'nt sound like that has anything to do with this, and it's not a jQuery function as far as I know, but it could be some sort of conflict ?

Comment: @adeneo this is strange.. var ytVideoDiv = 'a'; $j('#main').html(ytVideoDiv); < works fine, but when i do this var ytVideoDiv = 'a'; $j('.yt-video').html(ytVideoDiv) it doesn't work. have any idea what may be the problem?

Comment: There is nothing called `$j` in jQuery unless you defined it yourself. Unless your site is running jQuery with no-conflict and you defined it as `$j = $`, `$j = jQuery` or something similar, the function `$j()` does not exist.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned, I have this at the beginning "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();"

Comment: Ok well i figured out the problem and it is wordpress. I know your code works and that is all the question asked for so thanks! :]

EDIT: IM AN IDIOT.. the_content(); was placed after the call to locationOfVideo(); D:<

There wasn't even any text on the page when i called the function... wow.. im so smart. Anyways thanks @adeneo

Answer (score 1):

```
$j('#main .content:contains("<!--video-->")').replace('<--video-->', ytVideoDiv);
```

should be:

```
var videoNode = $j('#main .content:contains("<!--video-->")');
videoNode.html(videonode.html().replace('<!--video-->', ytVideoDiv));
```

or:

```
$j('#main .content:contains("<!--video-->")').html(function(index, oldhtml) { return oldhtml.replace('<--video-->', ytVideoDiv); });
```

Comment: You can also pass a function to `html`, you don't have to call it twice: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to output elements with special tag like abbr, check out javascript template usabe like [jquery-timeago](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago):

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-17T09:24:17Z">December 17, 2011</abbr>
```

replace:

```
$('abbr.timeago').timeago()
```